# Is it ok to omit the void parameter in a C function definition?

Tags: c, parameters, void, iso, function-declaration

I know that in modern C when we declare a function that has no parameter we must specify the void keyword like :

```
int fx(void);
```

However I have some doubts when it comes to function definitions. For example, are these two definitions the same ?

```
int fx(){} /* it is as if it was void */

int fx(void){}
```

I guess these two definitions are the same because I see a lot of code out there that omit the void keyword in the parameter....

Comment: In C23 you can omit `void` even in the declaration: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration

Comment: Both function definitions are invalid; the functions do not return a value like the signature says they do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is not invalid for a function declared with a non-void return type not to return a value. `int f(void) {} int main(void) { f(); }` is a program with behavior fully defined by the C standard. The only rule about this in the C standard is that if the value of the function is used, then the behavior is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Before the C23 Standard you may declare a function with a parameter type list or identifier list.

In this example of function declarations that are at the same time function definitions

```
int fx(){} /* it is as if it was void */

int fx(void){}
```

The first function declaration has an empty identifier list and the second function declaration has a parameter list with an unnamed parameter of the type `void` specifying that the function has no parameters. The second declaration provides a function prototype.

A question is raised relative to whether you may mix such declarations.
For example, whether these declarations are correct

```
int fx( void );

int fx(){}
```

According to the C17 Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))"

> 3 An identifier list in a function declarator that is not part of a
> definition of that function shall be empty.

and

> 14 An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters
> of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part
> of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no
> parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part
> of a definition of that function specifies that no information about
> the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

So as the function declaration that at the same time is its definition has an empty identifier list then and its declaration that is not at the same time is its definition shall also have an empty identifier list.

You may not mix function declarations of the same function with an identifier list and with parameter type list.

The C23 Standard removed the support for function definitions with identifier lists.

According to the C23 Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators)

> 13 For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is as if it were declared with a parameter type list consisting of the keyword void. A function declarator provides a prototype for the function

And there is a footnote (174):

> )This implies that a function definition without a parameter list
> provides a prototype, and that subsequent calls to that function in
> the same translation unit are constrained not to provide any argument
> to the function call. Thus a definition of a function without
> parameter list and one that has such a list consisting of the keyword
> void are fully equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

With `void` you get an error if parameters are passed to the function:

```
$ cat t.c
int fx()
{
   return 0;
}

int fx1(void)
{
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   fx(0);
   fx1(0);
   return 0;
}
$ gcc -pedantic -std=c89 -Wall t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:14:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘fx1’
   14 |         fx1(0);
      |         ^~~
t.c:6:5: note: declared here
    6 | int fx1(void)
      |     ^~~
```

**Edit**: Declaring `fx` with the signature `int fx(void)` and defining it with the signature `int fx()`, and declaring `fx1` with the signature `int fx()` and defining it with the signature `int fx(void)` will signal two errors in the code above. Therefor the most restrictive signature takes precedence over the other.

Comment: here we are talking about modern C and not c89 !

Comment: It's the same with C99 but not with C23 I've heard.

Comment: C89 is fully implemented by just about every current C compiler and that's the beauty of it. That cannot be said about later versions of standard C.

Answer (score -1):

Before C23, if the parameter is `void` in the declaration, the compiler will be able to detect an error if the function is called with some parameter :

```
int fx(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fx(1); // -> will produce an error at compile time
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if there's no parameter in declaration, the compiler won't check parameters on function call :

```
int fx();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fx(1, 2); // -> no error here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that. My question was about function definitions

Comment: @s3dev, I think that goes without saying since in modern C we only use prototypes

Comment: @s3dev, I know the difference between the two and I also know that modern C practice uses prototypes